# need a class i can deserialize my xml to without autogenerated code. Using automatically implemented properties

Tags: c#, xml, class, deserialization

Hey i want to make a class/object i can deserialize a xml string to, without using autogenerated code i want to use automatically implemented properties. Do anyone know how the object/class that i deserialize to should look like?

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(?????));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(json))
{
????? person = (?????)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

}
```

The xml that i want to deserialize from looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people type="array">
<person>
<author-id type="integer">542343801</author-id>
<background>Vi &#228;r har jobbat ihop och &#228;r v&#228;nner / Nathalie</background>
<company-id type="integer">81499881</company-id>
<created-at type="datetime">2011-08-10T08:39:45Z</created-at>
<first-name>Perdd</first-name>
<group-id type="integer" nil="true"></group-id>
<id type="integer">8153456700134</id>
<last-name>&quot;Cromwell&quot; (Eriksson)</last-name>
<owner-id type="integer" nil="true"></owner-id>
<title>&#228;gare, grafiker</title>
<updated-at type="datetime">2011-08-16T08:17:43Z</updated-at>
<visible-to>Everyone</visible-to>
<company-name>Studio company</company-name>
<linkedin-url nil="true">
</linkedin-url>    
<avatar_url>https://secure.highrisehq.com/avatar_proxy/eJxj4Yhmz2SWLWTMZHk2_TYLABiEBDM|9d29b49d8f165ff33f28b7f7fac2926eb8487319</avatar_url>
<contact-data>
<instant-messengers type="array"/>
<phone-numbers type="array">
<phone-number>
  <id type="integer">70306123</id>
  <location>Work</location>
  <number>0703689909</number>
</phone-number>
</phone-numbers>
<email-addresses type="array">
<email-address>
  <address>per@studiototal.se</address>
  <id type="integer">39720318</id>
  <location>Work</location>
</email-address>
</email-addresses>
<twitter-accounts type="array"/>
<addresses type="array"/>
<web-addresses type="array">
<web-address>
  <id type="integer">70306124</id>
  <location>Work</location>
  <url>http://www.studiototal.se</url>
</web-address>
</web-addresses>
</contact-data>
</person>



<person>
<author-id type="integer">848257</author-id>
<background></background>
<company-id type="integer">153838696</company-id>
<created-at type="datetime">2013-02-18T12:49:37Z</created-at>
<first-name>&quot;Kristofer&quot;</first-name>
<group-id type="integer" nil="true"></group-id>
<id type="integer">153838730</id>
<last-name>&quot;Malmer&quot;</last-name>
<owner-id type="integer" nil="true"></owner-id>
<title>Projektledare Online listening</title>
<updated-at type="datetime">2013-02-18T12:49:37Z</updated-at>
<visible-to>Everyone</visible-to>
<company-name>Santa Maria</company-name>
<linkedin-url nil="true"></linkedin-url>
<avatar_url>https://secure.highrisehq.com/avatar_proxy/eJxj4Yhmz2SWLWTMZOlK0eYEABUgAvk|d7e22f72a1a3ae2efa83df54e4184d429120cd9f</avatar_url>
<contact-data>
<instant-messengers type="array"/>
<phone-numbers type="array">
<phone-number>
  <id type="integer">129346649</id>
  <location>Work</location>
  <number>031-674151</number>
</phone-number>
</phone-numbers>
<email-addresses type="array"/>
<twitter-accounts type="array"/>
<addresses type="array"/>
<web-addresses type="array"/>
</contact-data>
</person>
</people>
```

This is what i got right now. But dont know how the contact data element and everything between contact-data should be converted to my object?

```
public class people
{
    public int author_id { get; set; }
    public string background { get; set; }
    public int company_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public int group_id { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public int owner_id { get; set; }
    public string company_name { get; set; }

    //contact-data ?????????????????????????
}
```

Comment: Contact data needs to be a separate class usually put a sibling of people class.

Comment: @jdweng can you show me how it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            People people = new People();
            People person = people.GetPeople(FILENAME);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("people")]
    public class People
    {
        [XmlElement("person")]
        public List<Person> person { get; set; }

        public People GetPeople(string filename)
        {
            People person = null;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(People));
            using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filename))
            {
                person = (People)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            return person;
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement("author_id")]
        public int author_id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("background")]
        public string background { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("company_id")]
        public int company_id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("created_at")]
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("first_name")]
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("group_id")]
        public int group_id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public long id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("last_name")]
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("owner_id")]
        public int owner_id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("company_name")]
        public string company_name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("avatar_url")]
        public string avatar_url { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("contact-data")]
        public Contact_Data contact_data { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("contact-data")]
    public class Contact_Data
    {
        [XmlElement("phone-numbers")]
        public Phone_Numbers phone_numbers { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("phone-numbers")]
    public class Phone_Numbers
    {
        [XmlElement("phone-number")]
        public List<Phone_Number> phone_number { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("phone-number")]
    public class Phone_Number
    {
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("location")]
        public string location { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("number")]
        public string number { get; set; }
    }

}
```